# more than one column from select

Tags: nhibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and I'm struggling with problem:

I have 3 tables and I need to present some data from these tables on DataGridView.
Normally - without hibernate, I have to make select and bind columns.

But I don't need all columns from these tables.
I have made sample project, where I select data from one table. And I store data as collection of hibernate poco object. Then I bind it as datasource to DataGridView and it is fine.

How to bind if I need columns from more than one table? 
Should I have one class with columns. Or 3 poco classes? Or I totally wrong and I need to make this on mapping level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to display data (and not change it), you could define a class for the objects you want to have listed in the DataGridView, e.g.

```
CombinedClassForGrid
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public PropertyA1 { get; set; }
    public PropertyB1 { get; set; }
    public PropertyB2 { get; set; }
}
```

With NHibernate you can query the tables like this, assuming that `ClassA` has a property `ClassBRef`:

```
ClassB bAlias = null;
CombinedClassForGrid cForGrid = null;

IList<CombinedClassForGrid> result = session.QueryOver<ClassA>()
    .JoinAlias(a => a.ClassBRef, () => bAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(a => a.Id).WithAlias(() => cForGrid.Id)
        .Select(a => a.Property1).WithAlias(() => cForGrid.PropertyA1)
        .Select(a => bAlias.Property1).WithAlias(() => cForGrid.PropertyB1)
        .Select(a => bAlias.Property2).WithAlias(() => cForGrid.PropertyB2))
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<CombinedClassForGrid>())
        .List<CombinedClassForGrid>();
```

Then you should be able to bind `result` to your DataGridView.